# How to use FXG as mx:Button icon

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to use a FXG image as the icon for a button that also contains a caption. My FXG file is located at resources/SpeakerIcon.fxg and my attempted usage looks like this in my mxml file:

```
     <mx:Button id="audioButton" label="Audio"
                   ....
                   icon="{resources.SpeakerIcon}"/>
```

When I try to use this I get "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert resources::SpeakerIcon@41fa0e1 to mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject." My research indicates that FXG files should be s:Graphics which do implement IFlexDisplayObject http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Graphic.html.

What simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<s:Graphics/>` object is different than the `<Graphics/>` tag in an FXG document.

`<s:Graphics/>` is the base class for Spark primitive shape components (like `<s:Rect/>`). These are not as lightweight as their FXG counterparts. As such they do not implement the `IFlexDisplayObject` interface (as @Flextras has just posted :)

FXG assets can be treated as `SpriteVisualElement` in your Flex code, which technically means FXG assets implement the `IVisualElement` interface.

If you can, use the Spark `<s:Button/>` class instead of mx. I don't think `<mx:Button/>` works with FXG.

Comment: +1 for the 'graphic' description.  If he uses s:Button instead of mx:Button he'll probably have to create a custom button skin to display the image as part of the button.  I didn't think the spark Button allows for an icon in the same way the MX Button does.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com `s:Button` has an [icon](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#style:icon) style since Flex 4.5: no custom skin required.

Comment: @RIAstar Awesome; I must have missed that addition.

Comment: +1 for "FXG assets can be treated as SpriteVisualElement in your Flex code". I got it working for me just by casting the fxg to a SpriteVIsualElement.

Answer (score 1):

For an FXG you should use a Sprite or [in your case] a [SpriteVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html).  I don't believe either of those classes implement IFlexDisplayObject.

You may consider wrapping your FXG element up in this [FXGImage](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/flex/whiteboard/jhouser/FXGImage/) class from my Apache Flex whiteboard.  FXGImage extends UIcomponent which is an IFlexDisplayObject.

Here is a direct link to the [source code for the class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/flex/whiteboard/jhouser/FXGImage/Workspace/FXGImageLibrary/src/org/apache/utils/FXGImage.as?revision=1310637&view=markup).